# Can we change background color of checkbox text in WxPython?

Tags: wxpython

Can we change background color of checkbox text in WxPython?
I want the whole region of the square box + attached text to it, to be in a particular color

```
checkbox = wx.CheckBox(self.panel, -1, 'Label',  (5, 5)
```

So the goal is to change the **background** color of the checkbox and label

checkbox.SetBackgroundColour('blue') only changes the square of the checkbox to blue, but I'd like everything but that (including the label's background)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes just

```
import wx
```

then define your class

```
class my_window(wx.Frame):
```

set the size

```
wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'My Window', size=(300,200))
```

and the colour

```
self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)
```

For labels you have to use SetForegroundColor

```
  self.label2.SetForegroundColour("yellow")
```

Comment: How about a checkbox? cb = wx.CheckBox(...). cb.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE) only colors the checkbox, but i want the label too

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the check box widget supports that. Even if it does, it may not support it on all platforms. Because wxPython wraps the native widgets as much as possible, sometimes the native widget doesn't allow the changing of foreground or background or both colors. What's really confusing is when one version of an OS allows it and the other doesn't.

What Rachel is proposing above is to set the entire panel a different color. This could work if you stack panels. Put a panel on a frame, then put another panel on top of the main panel and put the check box on top of the second panel. You may have to set the size of the panel manually though.

Or you may have to write a custom widget yourself. There are examples in wx.lib and on the wxPython wiki.

Answer (score 0):

self.checkbox.SetBackgroundColour( wx.Colour( 255, 255, 128 ) )

I got this from the code generated by wxFormBuilder. I find it easier to try to design the look first then modify it further to fit my needs..